# Update to XCode 8.3.1: Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group with Snapkit error

Tags: xcode, snapkit

Just updated to Xcode 8.3.1 and build my project get the errors like:

```
 "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg6heightCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:

  "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg5widthCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:

  "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg6centerCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:

  "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg7centerXCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:

  "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg6bottomCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:

  "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg7leadingCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:

  "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg7centerYCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:

  "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg8trailingCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:

  "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg3topCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Seems it's SnapKit issue.

- Tried `cmd + shift + k`
- Removed `pod 'SnapKit'` `pod install` and added it back still not work.

If it's not version issue. How to debug/solve these kind of errors. Thanks.

**EDIT**
Right click the error in project navigator, then choose **Reveal in Log** show more error information:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TFE7SnapKitPS_23ConstraintAttributesDSLg6heightCS_14ConstraintItem", referenced from:
      __TFFC6Auroma22AURAlarmViewController19configureBottomViewFCSo6UIViewT_U2_FC7SnapKit15ConstraintMakerT_ in AlarmViewController.o
```

I can see `AlarmViewController` called SnapKit layout methods. But still not clear why the error were there.

**EDIT**
My previous Xcode should be 8.3.

Comment: You haven't just updated Xcode. You have updated Swift. That's the important info. It'd also be important to know from which older version you're coming.

Comment: From previous Xcode 8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved by removing `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.